# Serving Python scripts with CGIHTTPServer on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, cgi

I'm trying to set up Python's `CGIHTTPServer` on Mac OS X to be able to serve CGI scripts locally, but I seem to be unable to do this.

I've got a simple test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi

cgi.test()
```

It has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x@` and is located in `~/WWW` (with permissions `drwxr-xr-x`). It runs just fine from the shell and I have this script to serve them using `CGIHTTPServer`:

```
import CGIHTTPServer
import BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler):
    cgi_directories = ["~/WWW"]

PORT = 8000

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
```

But when I run it, going to `localhost:8000` just serves the content of the script, not the result (i.e. it gives back the code, not the output).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paths in `cgi_directories` are matched against the path part of the URL, not the actual filesystem path. Setting it to `["/"]` or `[""]` will probably work better.